# Restrict the number of entries in a relation based on conditions across several relations

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL and am trying to restrict the number of concurrent loans that a student can have. To do this, I have created a CTE that selects all unreturned loans grouped by StudentID, and counts the number of unreturned loans for each StudentID. Then, I am attempting to create a check constraint that uses that CTE to restrict the number of concurrent loans that a student can have to 7 at most.

The below code does not work because it is syntactically invalid, but hopefully it can communicate what I am trying to achieve. Does anyone know how I could implement my desired restriction on loans?

```sql
CREATE TABLE loan (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   copy_id INTEGER REFERENCES media_copies (copy_id),
   account_id INT REFERENCES account (id),
   loan_date DATE NOT NULL,
   expiry_date DATE NOT NULL,
   return_date DATE,

   WITH currentStudentLoans (student_id, current_loans) AS
   (
      SELECT account_id, COUNT(*)
      FROM loan
      WHERE account_id IN (SELECT id FROM student)
         AND return_date IS NULL
      GROUP BY account_id
   )

   CONSTRAINT max_student_concurrent_loans CHECK(
      (SELECT current_loans FROM currentStudentLoans) BETWEEN 0 AND 7 
   )
);
```

For additional (and optional) context, I include an ER diagram of my database schema.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this using an in-line CTE like this.  You have several choices.

The first is a UDF and `check` constraint.  Essentially, the logic in the CTE is put in a UDF and then a `check` constraint validates the data.

The second is a trigger to do the check on this table.  However, that is tricky because the counts are on the same table.

The third is storing the total number in another table -- probably `accounts` -- and keeping it up-to-date for `insert`s, `update`s, and `delete`s on this table.  Keeping that value up-to-date requires triggers on `loans`.  You can then put the `check` constraint on `accounts`.

I'm not sure which solution fits best in your overall schema.  The first is closest to what you are doing now.  The third "publishes" the count, so it is a bit clearer what is going on.